# statsmodels.adfuller weird behaviour of usedlag value

Tags: time-series, statsmodels, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I'm learning about time-series analysis and have two series on which I'm performing an Augmented Dickey-Fuller test in order to check for stationarity.

I'm trying to understand why I get very different behavior/results for two related datasets.

The main thing that confuses me is why the `adfuller()` method for `B` returns `0` for the returned `usedlag` variable. I suspect that this might be the reason why the p-values differ so much?

**Could someone explain to me what's going on and if I should be doing something differently?**

For "A" I get the following output:

```
adfuller(A)

(-2.462353401491699,
 0.12490485039491572,
 7,
 33,
 {'1%': -3.6461350877925254,
  '5%': -2.954126991123355,
  '10%': -2.6159676124885216},
 27.70941757902819)
```

And this is the output for the "B":

```
adfuller(B)

(-3.4701626831437498,
 0.008787271377867082,
 0,
 40,
 {'1%': -3.6055648906249997, '5%': -2.937069375, '10%': -2.606985625},
 48.4042735403956)
```

This is a plot of the two series:
[image: Plot of the data]

This is the data I'm using:

```
A = [0.0854392896410088, 0.2724713789027663, -0.08311822577904612, -0.15875825322208784, -0.5636552395971745, -0.35411229142554207, -0.4686775168205056, -0.6161577020644173, -0.7494262849022828, -1.19866168497766, -0.010353445463754357, -0.12581168147117452, -0.6166324007971552, -0.6252482695351813, -1.3890389232362814, -0.35402743763678224, -0.09346708309297454, 0.010700603471345896, 0.00033439762068122745, -0.43097207789627506, -0.5400340799832378, -0.2900498597687255, -0.6536394122977347, -0.7217821618570142, -0.534208546082492, -0.6669775699201006, 0.6853791773462524, -0.3287600091879562, -0.3699457680457272, -0.6924630239075774, -0.8188635619050852, -0.7802537475684734, -0.5832578040664049, -0.958203945811412, -0.3328368748495661, -0.3734740361584033, 0.051332098624002474, -0.03647474401647896, -0.34443373961728807, -0.4201788921905459, 0.13982402521441342]

B = [0.5873685003686321, 0.5187156535690635, 0.06380493995006327, 0.32810622588952515, -0.10153506691483231, -0.16098168092682436, -0.5225595533605951, 0.24091951443591636, 0.5701779424355137, 0.026661134925188113, -0.07332321192373002, 0.0652324864999202, -0.3069686300207766, -0.3825036334496649, -1.269559128852338, -0.2676325553069426, 0.20946657790085813, -0.203716792857451, -0.2533472017321723, -0.522254640325575, -0.24539839242407088, -0.4513556999360337, -0.6377463396845843, -0.4700144180378964, -0.2517505596183048, -0.16300007769826763, 0.6026137895446362, -0.3459972097858011, -0.6421562668858238, -0.87608166601833, -0.48052469244016593, -0.3743945887167281, -0.3413721151746583, -1.0127934717473184, 0.6690843230485171, 0.9221642659781699, 0.7168153880173251, 0.4611720910887281, -0.043179678245897, 0.9276657232654817, 0.7862306218632784]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe that the output of `adfuller(B)` shows 40 as the number of observations although the length of the original series is 41.
In order to test for the unit root, the Dickey-Fuller test represents time series as an auto-regressive process of the first order and transforms it via differencing:

$$
\Delta y_t = \gamma y_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t
$$

where $\Delta y_t$ is the first-order difference with respect to $y_t$, $y_{t-1}$ is the previous value, and $\varepsilon_t$ is the white noise. Since the original time series is differenced, the number of observations is reduced by 1.

The Augmented Dickey-Fuller test is just an extension of the Dickey-Fuller test which allows representing the first-order difference as an autoregressive process (by including the lags of itself), and thus account for autocorrelation.

$$
\Delta y_{t} = \gamma y_{t-1} + \delta_1 \Delta y_{t-1} + ... + \delta_{p-1} \Delta y_{t-p+1} + \varepsilon_t
$$

where $p$ is the order of the original autoregressive process.
The value of `usedlag` in the output of the function `adfuller()` represents the number of additional lagged differences in the equation above: if it's 0, then no additional lags are included, and the model is fit as in the original Dickey-Fuller test. In your example `adfuller(A)` used 7 lags and thus reduced the number of the differenced values to 33 (40 minus 7).

The statsmodels' implementation of `adfuller()` by default selects the best fit among the models with different number of lagged differences starting with 0, and up to the number specified in the `maxlag` parameter according to the Akaike information criterion. This can be overridden though by setting `autolag` as `None`, and specifying a certain number in `maxlag` which will be then used as $(p-1)$.